# Compose navigation - state not always restored

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm having a problem using compose navigation and bottom navigation bar. Using these navOptions, the state is not always restored when going back to a previously selected tab in the bottom navigation.

```
val topLevelNavOptions = navOptions {
  popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
    saveState = true
  }
  launchSingleTop = true
  restoreState = true
}
```

When clicking through the screens sporadically, I lose the state and get new instances of the viewmodels injected using hilt.

Similar behaviour be observed in the [nowinandroid](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) app.
Clone the repository and add the following to `InterestsViewModel.kt`:

```
override fun onCleared() {
  super.onCleared()
  Log.d("asd", "onCleared")
}
```

Then proceed to sporadically click through the screens using the bottom navigation. The log statement above will be printed... sometimes

Does anyone know why the state is lost/reset and how to prevent that from happening?

**EDIT**

I believe this is a bug in navigation compose. Reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265838050